# Couchbase SDK and Moxi Client

Tags: couchbase

I am new to Couchbase and trying to understand why we need a Client side proxy like Moxi if using a Couchbase PHP SDK.

As per my understanding the proxying of client requests to right server is done by the Client SDK which maintains the vBucket map of all keys.

Why in case of a web application using PHP SDK and Couchbase, we need an additional Moxi client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are for two different things.

1. Moxi is for when you want to use a standard memcached library as MOXI will proxy memcached calls to the Couchbase cluster and use Couchbase buckets. Your code will not know it is talking to a persistent database in the background. Using moxi with Couchbase buckets will give you some of the benefits of Couchbase, like High Availability, easy scalability and performance Couchbase is known for, but you can use any old off the shelf memcached library. Just know that because of adhering to memcached, moxi is limited to that functionality from an application perspective.
   In my opinion, moxi should be used to bridge the gap between people on memcached and using the full SDKs and is not meant to be a final destination, though some people have been on it for years.
2. Using the Couchbase PHP SDK on the other hand gives you the full suite functionality that Couchbase can offer and you do not need MOXI at all.

In summary, if you are in a spot to use the Couchbase SDK, do that. You will get more functionality, performance, etc. from it. Moxi is for those that are already have memcached, but want to step up to a clustered high performance cache and not change their code.

Comment: moxi can be used with memcached bucket too.