# Is there a proxy with Couchbase memcached bucket?

Tags: memcached, couchbase

We are using Couchbase 5.1.1, a cluster of 5 VMs, **memcached bucket**. I try to understand how memcache bucket work within a couchbase cluster.

Php is speaking memcache directly to couchbase servers (no explicit proxy).

But sometime, I see error: `SERVER_ERROR proxy downstream timeout` looks like there is a proxy somewhere?

**Test with Docker:**

1. `docker run --name cb --rm -ti couchbase:5.1.1`

Then inside the container:

2. `couchbase-cli cluster-init --cluster localhost --cluster-username admin --cluster-password totototo --cluster-name poc`
3. `couchbase-cli bucket-create --username admin --password totototo --cluster localhost --bucket mem --bucket-type memcached --bucket-ramsize 128 --bucket-port 11212`

I can see **a moxi process now**:

```
> /opt/couchbase/bin/moxi -B auto -z
> url=http://127.0.0.1:8091/pools/default/bucketsStreaming/mem -Z
> port_listen=11212,downstream_max=1024,downstream_conn_max=4,connect_max_errors=5,connect_retry_interval=30000,connect_timeout=400,auth_timeout=100,cycle=200,downstream_conn_queue_timeout=200,downstream_timeout=5000,wait_queue_timeout=200 -p 0 -Y y -O stderr
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couchbase SDK and Moxi Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371622/couchbase-sdk-and-moxi-client)

Comment: [That error message is coming from Moxi](http://source.couchbase.org/source/search?q=%22proxy+downstream+timeout%22&project=Couchbase_Server), which routes standard memcached requests to the Couchbase cluster.

Comment: I use a memcached bucket, Moxi should not be enabled here, isnit? Or maybe Moxi is here because the cluster?

Comment: Moxi is one of the underlying server processes that make up Couchbase Server. if I understand the [5.0 release notes](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/5.0/release-notes/relnotes.html) correctly, server-side Moxi is deprecated, and users are encouraged to use Couchbase client SDKs (or client-side Moxi if using a Couchbase SDK is not possible).

Comment: Here's [some Couchbase documentation on server-side and client-side Moxi](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/install/install-client-server.html).

Comment: I am using a memcached bucket, not couchbase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually yes, before Couchbase 5.5.X:

> a moxi process is run as soon as a memcached bucket is created.

After and at 5.5.X:

> no more moxi proxy, you can run moxi or configure application to distribute data over the cluster